# Bootcamp trackpad: Left tap while dragging with other finger

Tags: windows-10, macbook, touchpad, boot-camp

I'm running Windows 10 under MBP bootcamp. I wonder if there is any way of (specifically) enabling the LEFT-tap click while moving the cursor with an other finger, so when I left-tap, 2 fingers are down on the trackpad at the same time (but one was already down moving and the other one made the tap later).

I have tried with bootcamp configs and trackpad++ but there is no option. In MACOS I think this is default.

Comment: As no-one's picked up on this yet - I don't think Windows can do it. Its touchpad capabilities took a long time to catch up to Mac & I still think they're not yet fully caught up.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me on a 2012 MBP with Windows 10 installed.

1. Install bootcamp 6.0.
2. Download and open bootcamp 5.1.5640 installer.
3. Run the trackpad driver installer (bootcamp->drivers->apple->applemultitouchtrackpadinstller64.exe).
4. Open devmgmt.msc -> human interface devices -> apple multi-touch.
5. Update driver -> browse my computer -> let me pick from a list.
6. Switch driver from "multi-touch" to "multitouch".

I had to repeat the procedure after an update to Win 10 20H2.